# React applying filter to array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

Im creating a filtration in the E-commerce project. I have data like

```js
const gender = ["male"]
const brand = ["adidas","nike"]
const price =[100]
//note: gender,brand,price are not static array, it can single element or more than that.

const allProducts = [
{brand:"puma",gender:"male",price:50},
{brand:"nike",gender:"male",price:90},
{brand:"adidas",gender:"female",price:110},
{brand:"adidas",gender:"male",price:95},]
```

Now, I want to filter all products based on gender, brand, and price. I should get all the products having gender male with brand Adidas and Nike and price less than 100.

I have achieved the result for the brand alone, like this

```js
const[filteredprod,setFilteredprod]=useState()

allProducts.forEach((value)=>{
            for(var i=0;i<brand.length;i++){
            if(value.brand===brand?.[i])
            {setFilteredProd = value
            )}}
      })
```

But I want to do to brand gender price simultaneously and get the product. How can I do that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allProducts.filter((item)=>(item.brand === 'adidas' || item.brand === 'nike') && item.price<100 && item.gender === 'male');`

For dynamically checking the condition,

`allProducts.filter((item)=>brand.includes(item.brand)&& item.price<price[0] && gender.includes(item.gender));`

Comment: I want to dynamically check the values from the array of brands, prices, and gender. you ave given static values

Comment: Nice, thank you! it works. This is what I was figuring out how to loop through each array at the same. I didn't know about includes() methods thanks.

Comment: what can be done if there are multiple price in price=[50,100] how to check less condition for each?

Comment: you can use this syntax price.every((priceItem)=>item.price<priceItem) . This will test whether item.price is smaller than all the elements of the array. Also you can just check  whether item.price is smaller than the largest element in price array. syntax is item.price < Math.max(...price)

Answer (score 1):

You can add another condition to your if statement within your forEach loop.

```js
allProducts.forEach((value)=>{
            for(var i=0;i<brand.length;i++){
            if(value.brand===brand?.[i] && value.gender === 'male' && value.price <100)
            {setFilteredProd = value
            )}}
      })
```

However the more standard practice would be to use the array method filter.

```js
allProducts.filter(({ brand, price, gender) => (brand === 'adidas' || brand === 'nike') && price < 100 && gender === 'male');
```

Comment: Ya but this will be considered a static method, the gender can be female or male while the price can be anything. I want a dynamic method to check with all te element from the arrays

Comment: Then you need to pass in state values instead of the hard coded values. E.g, [dynamicPrice, setDynamicPrice] = useState(50)) ... allProducts.filter(({ brand, price, gender) => (brand === 'adidas' || brand === 'nike') && price < dynamicPrice && gender === 'male');

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got the solution, includes( ) in array.filter( ) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const gender = ["male"]
const brand = ["adidas", "nike"]
const price = [100]

const allProducts = [{
    brand: "puma",
    gender: "male",
    price: 50
  },
  {
    brand: "nike",
    gender: "male",
    price: 90
  },
  {
    brand: "adidas",
    gender: "female",
    price: 110
  },
  {
    brand: "adidas",
    gender: "male",
    price: 95
  },
]

console.log(allProducts.filter(product => {
      if (product.gender === gender[0] && 
      product.price < price[0] &&
      (product.brand === brand[0] || product.brand === brand[1])) {
          return true
        }
        return false
      }))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got the solution, includes( ) in array.filter( ) works for me.